# Add consecutive tags to an array of images

Tags: arrays, swift, tags

I'm new to Swift and got stuck on something I've been experimenting.

Big picture:
I want to set up an app where I will have a set of images and when you press on an image it will produce a specific sound allocated to it.

Problem:
I have an array of images in the collectionView and was hoping that if I could automatically assign a tag to the images consecutively then I could line up the sounds according to the tag and link the sound to the image that way.

I have been playing around with the tag assignments for a few hours now and can't seem to be able to do it. The best I've got is set out below, could anyone help?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class basicVocabViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer?

    let cards = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
    let cardImages: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "1")!,
        UIImage(named: "2")!,
        UIImage(named: "3")!,
        UIImage(named: "4")!,
    ]

    // Assign tag to each UIImage

    var cardImages.tag = 0
    var currentTag = 0
    for counter in cardImages {

        let firstImage.tag = currentTag
        currentTag += 1

    }
}
```

Comment: I might add something to @Frankenstein answer. Note that his/her loop directly assigns the tag value where your's tries to declare it by using `let`. I really don't know what the result is for your code, as `let` is a way of declaring a constant variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can only assign `tag` on a `UIView`. So, use `UIImageView` to set a tag. Just use a loop for the array of `UIImageView` as follows:

```swift
let cardImageViews = [UIImageView]()
for (index, imageView) in cardImageViews.enumerated() {
    imageView.tag = index
}
```